# Where is Android 4.1 (Jelly bean) source code?

Tags: android-source

I am looking for Android 4.1(jelly bean) source code. Over the internet there are lots of blog mentioning that source code has been published. But I couldn't figure out where.

I looked here http://source.android.com/ , But it is showing source code for Android 4.0. I downloaded the whole repo but couldn't fine the 4.1 branch. Am I missing something here?

Can Any one help me to find the source code?

***EDIT***
Until now source.android.com is not update with the latest download instructions. If I use the command suggested by "Landervdb" then it works. I also found some more resources for Android source code. These are given below.
[Androidxref.com](http://androidxref.com/4.1.1/)
[github.com](https://github.com/android)

For more information you can also check post on [Android jelly bean source code](http://code4reference.com/2012/07/android-jelly-bean-source-code/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I currently don't have access to a linux box where I can test this, but I can see the manifest for Jelly Bean on the AOSP website. You should be able to download the source by issuing the following commands:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.1.1_r3
repo sync
```

For a more detailed description, please refer to http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html. This document has not been updated for Jelly Bean but it *should* work, just replace the version numbers where appropriate.

Comment: The only thing that you should correct is that branch is called android-4.1.1_r1

Comment: android-4.1.1_r3 is in there too, that should be a more recent version, no? Anyway, either would be fine I guess.

Comment: Do not know actually, never tried to download something other than r1 ) I guess, you are right.

Comment: Here is a helpful tags list with notes on that @Yury http://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html#source-code-tags-and-builds

Answer (score 2):

Android 4.1 is already available through

repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.1.1_r1