# Android JellyBean 4.2 Source Code

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, audio-player, android-music-player

Where can I find Source Code for JellyBean 4.2 Music Player Source Code? Is it available in any site? I could not find anywhere. Tried https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Music/+refs but haven't found 4.2 there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is Android 4.1 (Jelly bean) source code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618907/where-is-android-4-1-jelly-bean-source-code)

Comment: Searched that site but haven't found that

Comment: Maybe https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Music/+/android-4.2.2_r1.2

Comment: Got that finally. Thank you @tynn